# Access dictionary value in JSON doc that is also a dictionary, and convert inner dict to a string

Tags: python, json

I'm having trouble accessing multiple 'value' keys inside of the 'variables' list. I can access a single 'value', but when I try grabbing a value it chokes saying it indexes need to be an int or a slice. Using an int works, but I need mulitple values.

This works:

```
for item in data['mcsResults']['sanityChecks']:
    print(item['variables'][0]['value'])  #int
```

This does not:

```
for item in data['mcsResults']['sanityChecks']:
    print(item['variables'][:]['value'])   #slice
```

JSON is here. The second 'sanityCheck' is has the 'variables' list I'm after:

```
{'mcsResults': {'mcsDecision': {'decision': 'STANDARD',
   'type': 'CLASSIFICATION',
   'usedDefaultDecision': False,
   'message': 'Classification is Standard',
   'rationale': None,
   'criteria': [{'id': 14,
     'name': 'STANDARD Classification',
     'type': 'CLASSIFICATION',
     'classification': 'STANDARD',
     'description': 'Determine if Model Classification is STANDARD',
     'criteriaMet': True,
     'priority': 0,
     'message': None,
     'variables': [{'name': 'modelPredictionScore',
       'value': 406.9856574239477},
      {'name': 'min', 'value': 300.0},
      {'name': 'max', 'value': 599.99}],
     'lastUpdatedDate': '2019-07-21T00:28:19.059'}]},
  'sanityChecks': [{'id': 1,
    'name': 'Validate State',
    'type': 'SANITY_CHECK',
    'classification': None,
    'description': 'Validate State',
    'criteriaMet': False,
    'priority': 1,
    'message': 'Valid state',
    'variables': [{'name': 'rt_st_cd', 'value': 'NE'}],
    'lastUpdatedDate': '2018-05-17T20:04:48.597'},
   {'id': 8,
    'name': 'Validate Account Discount',
    'type': 'SANITY_CHECK',
    'classification': None,
    'description': 'Validate Account Discount',
    'criteriaMet': False,
    'priority': 1,
    'message': 'Valid Account Discount',
    'variables': [{'name': 'other_lob_subcd',
      'value': {'OOP1': 'DWELLING', 'OOP2': 'DWELLING'}},
     {'name': 'other_lobcd', 'value': {'OOP1': 'HOME', 'OOP2': 'HOME'}}],
    'lastUpdatedDate': '2018-05-17T20:04:48.607'},
```

Comment: What's your question then? It appears that you are able to grab the value

Comment: @PL200 Yes, I can get it when there's a single value. I pointed out the final sanityCheck(id:8) in the doc as having 2 'value' keys. I can only get the first one, but when I getting all 'value' keys by slicing, I get the error: list indexes need to be int or slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put one more loop inside or

```
for item in data['mcsResults']['sanityChecks']:
  for val_obj in item['variables']:
    print(val_obj['value'])
```

use Python's list comprehension, if you want to keep a single line

```
for item in data['mcsResults']['sanityChecks']:
  [print(val_obj['value']) for val_obj in item['variables']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this get the data you need, you can parse from there:

```
for items in data['mcsResults']['sanityChecks']: 
   for item in items['variables']: 
        print(item) 
# {'name': 'rt_st_cd', 'value': 'NE'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the values in this way - the slice notation `[:]` gives you a copy of the list, it does not iterate trough it. You will need another loop to access the different dictionaries in that list

```
>>> item = {'variables': [{'name': 'other_lob_subcd','value': {'OOP1': 'DWELLING', 'OOP2': 'DWELLING'}},{'name': 'other_lobcd', 'value': {'OOP1': 'HOM
E', 'OOP2': 'HOME'}}]}
>>> print(item['variables'][:]) #notice this is the same list
[{'name': 'other_lob_subcd', 'value': {'OOP1': 'DWELLING', 'OOP2': 'DWELLING'}}, {'name': 'other_lobcd', 'value': {'OOP1': 'HOME', 'OOP2': 'HOME'}}]
>>> [var['value'] for var in item['variables']]
[{'OOP1': 'DWELLING', 'OOP2': 'DWELLING'}, {'OOP1': 'HOME', 'OOP2': 'HOME'}]
```